# CUDA with visual studio and cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, cmake

I am working with CUDA 8.0 and Visual Studio 2013. 
Until now I have been building my VS-Solutions with CMake and it is working pretty well. 
Normally a cuda project is build with following code snippet:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}/../lib/x64)
```

The CUDA-project is working, compiling and running without any problems. But I am missing the CUDA C/C++ field in the project properties. When I create a VS-Solution directly in VS, I can choose NVIDIA/ CUDA 8.0 and the properties are there (as you can see in the picture below)
[image]

**Question:**
Is it possible to generate a project with CMake and with the CUDA properties project option?

Thanks and I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Not sure about this since I don't use cuda however with `CMake` based projects in Visual Studio you generally don't touch these property pages because all your settings get thrown out every time you generate.

Comment: It seems at least some of these settings are available in `CMake`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindCUDA.html

Comment: thanks for you comments. I know that cmake will override the settings, nevertheless I wanted the cuda properties dialog directly in VS. But I will accept that it is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some month passed since I asked myself this question...
And now the new version of CMake enables CUDA as a first-class language with [version 3.8](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/release/3.8.html).

This means, now it is possible to create CUDA targets with this simple command  [(doku)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/enable_language.html#command:enable_language):

```
enable_language(CUDA)
```

This functionality of CMake offers to create CUDA-targets with using the cmake-commands `add_executable` or `add_library` **without** the need for using the `find_package(CUDA)` or `cuda_add_executable()` commands.

However, CMake's Version 3.8 does not include the support for Visual Studio's IDE - But [Version 3.9](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/release/3.9.html) does (Hooray!!). The properties project options in VS are available now.

Conclusion:
If you work with CUDA and Visual Studio, it will be absolutely worth it to switch to CMake 3.9 and this great new functionality.